# Can't compile app after adding activity

Tags: android, compiler-errors

My app was compiling fine and running without problem. I then went to add a new activity using the File > New > Other...

I normally never add activities using this tool as I have been weary in the past that it actually causes more damage to my app than its worth. But today, I yielded to my urge to give it another try instead of just copying and pasting an existing activity. And sure enough, the same BS happened as I feared. It messed up my app and now I cannot compile it. Rule #1: stay away from these shit tools that Google delivers. Do EVERYTHING from hand. I tried doing a clean multiple times and even deleted the bin and gen folders but of no avail. Here is what the error window is reporting:

```
Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
```

Comment: What is your class name? which Editor you are using? Are you using library to project?

Comment: What do you mean which class name? My app has tons of classes. I'm using Eclipse. No library. Like I said, the project was working fine until I used that crap tool to add an activity.

Comment: logs says the problem while compiling v4 jar, thats why I am asking? Try to remove and add v4 jar again..

Comment: Is your new activity extending `Activity` class? And are you sure it is defined in the `Manifest`?

Comment: The outcome also depends on the choices you made during the "Add New Activity Wizard". Using your VCS tool you should be able to pinpoint what the "wizard" changed in your project and you could fix by gradually reverting some of the changes.

Comment: I even removed the activity that got added and this problem persists. It clearly messed up something in the configuration. I also don't know what the v4 jar is. My app is using V13.

Comment: @janos: No wizard should mess your app to the point that it cannot compile. This is pure garbage.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately I always have backups of my projects. I simply took the last backup and overwrote the entire project and the problem was fixed. Take my advice after having experienced this multiple times - stay away from using Google's Wizards in Eclipse to add code. The amount of damage they do isn't worth it.